# How to get the result of specific column using specific column name as array index?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array , I want to get result by passing **currency** parameter .
E.g $array is the variable containing array.

I want to get by this way **$array['EUR']['rate']**

How can i get by this way. Please Help

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Andorra
            [code] => AD
            [currency] => EUR
            [phone] => +376
            [rate] => 5727.21
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => United Arab Emirates
        [code] => AE
        [currency] => AED
        [phone] => +971
        [rate] => 24341.9
    )
)
```

I want to get

Comment: I think it would be more convenient if you use currency code as array indexes instead of number indexes.

Comment: This is coming from database how can i edit the array index.?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $currency) {
    if ($currency['currency'] == 'EUR') {
        echo $currency['rate'];
    }
}
```

You may want to format the array differently to be able to access data directly without looping. So you could use currency as key.

You can reformat the array like this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $currency) {
    $newArray[$currency['currency']] = $currency;
}
```

Then access `$newArray['EUR']['rate']`

Answer (score 0):

Stick it in a getCurrency function. Then just pass in the one you want and the array:

```
<?php

$x = [
    [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Andorra',
            'code' => 'AD',
            'currency' => 'EUR',
            'phone' => '+376',
            'rate' => '5727.21',
        ],

[
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'United Arab Emirates',
        'code' => 'AE',
        'currency' => 'AED',
        'phone' => '+971',
        'rate' => '24341.9',
    ]
];

function getCurrency($code, $currenciesArray)
{
    foreach ($currenciesArray as $row) {
        if ($row['currency'] == $code) {
            return $row;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$currency = getCurrency('EUR', $x);
echo $currency['rate'];  // outputs 5727.21
```

See it here https://3v4l.org/DnDQo

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function formatArray($array){
   $return = [];
   foreach($array as $arrayItem){
     $return[$arrayItem['currency']] = $arrayItem;
   }
   return $return;
}
```

current array

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Andorra
                [code] => AD
                [currency] => EUR
                [phone] => +376
                [rate] => 5727.21
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => United Arab Emirates
            [code] => AE
            [currency] => AED
            [phone] => +971
            [rate] => 24341.9
        )
    )
```

So using this function

```
print_r(formatArray($array));
```

arry will convert to this:

```
    Array
    (
        [EUR] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Andorra
                [code] => AD
                [currency] => EUR
                [phone] => +376
                [rate] => 5727.21
            )

    [AED] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => United Arab Emirates
            [code] => AE
            [currency] => AED
            [phone] => +971
            [rate] => 24341.9
        )
    )
```

then you can try like this:

```
echo $array['EUR']['rate'];
```